# iPhone managing reusable UIImages and UIViews

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

What is the best way to keep my UI constants in seperate class accesible from all controllers?

UIView, UIImage and UIColour all these images and colours create a such mess of allocations and releases in my controllers and most of them are even same. Instead of alloc/relase the same images and views, CAlayers over and over again in different classes, I want to create them once, cache them (or something like that) and easily access when needed.

I want to keep memory and my code clean.

Comment: I did not get what you are trying to say.
I alloc the object and take responsibility to release it after using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes , its possible

create a class like gconstants , then store all your string here in h/m files

```
 extern NSString *const APP_TITLE;

 @interface UIColor (APP)
+(UIColor *) APP_NAV_COLOR;
 @end
```

in .m file

```
 NSString *const APP_TITLE = @"APP Name";

@implementation UIColor (APP)

+(UIColor *) APP_NAV_COLOR { return [UIColor colorWithRed:00/256.0 green:111/256.0    
 blue:59/256.0 alpha:1.0]; }
```

@end

and in any controller declare the header file

```
 self.title = APP_TITLE;
```

Comment: tnx do I need to add multiple intarface and implementation in one class? and also what is exactly "APP" here in implementation UIColor (APP)

Comment: @xdeveloper : is my app name!

Answer (score 2):

You could use some macro's defined in a header file which you can then include in all the appropriate implementation files, or even in your `prefix.pch` if you want to make them available to every file in your project.

As an example, imagine a header file called `Config.h`

For a shared `UIColor` you could add the following ...

```
#define SOME_CONSTANT_COLOR    [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5f green:0.5f blue:0.5f alpha:0.5f]
```

And then you can access it the same way as you would use any other macro ...

```
#import "Config.h" // at the top of you implmentation file, or prefix header

someView.backgroundColor = SOME_CONSTANT_COLOR;
```

The same also goes for images as well ..

```
#define SOME_IMAGE    [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"]; // In config.h

myImageView.image = SOME_IMAGE; // In implementation file
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to show image support; you can pretty much do anything you like this way as long as the class returns an autoreleased object (i.e. where you don't have to alloc/init)

Comment: tnx! what is difference between this method and creating a singleton class? performance is kidna important, I will be using alot if CAlayers, gradients,,etc.

Comment: I'm not too sure about the performance differences but look at it this way, using macros instead of a singleton means one less object to initialise that would otherwise provide only the same functionality.