# iPhone UIColor in Plist file

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

Is that possible to save colorcodes in Plist file somehow?

Do I have to represent them in string? and then can I create colors from them?

I saw a similar thread here about this but it has no answer yet

What could be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIColor` ([see here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol ([see here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSCoding)) meaning you can write them out to a plist if you do it using `NSCoding`.

There is a great tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/how-to-save-your-app-data-with-nscoding-and-nsfilemanager) about saving and restoring your app data using `NSCoding`

Comment: tnx can you have a look also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911956/iphone-managing-reusable-uiimages-and-uiviews

Comment: I have also answered that question :)

Answer (score 4):

I can give you a suggestion. Instead of storing the color names you can store the RGB values in a array and store that array in each row in the plist.

key - Red
Type - Array
value - 1.0,0.0,0.0

Retrieve the array for each key.

```
NSArray *colorsArray = [dictionaryFromPlist objectForKey:@"Red"];
UIColor *mycolor = [UIColor colorWithRed:[[colorsArray objectAtIndex:0] floatValue]
                                   green:[[colorsArray objectAtIndex:1] floatValue]
                                    blue:[[colorsArray objectAtIndex:2] floatValue]
                                   alpha:1.0];
```

Just my thought..

Comment: tnx if it is with alpha channel?

Comment: store it in next index in the plist array  value - 1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0

Answer (score 2):

You can use **NSKeyedArchiver** which inherits from NSCoder

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[UIColor purpleColor]];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{@"color": data}];
```

To get the color back out you would use **NSKeyedUnarchiver**:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation];
NSLog(@"%@", [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: dict[@"color"]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

To preserve human readability, I did a category for this:

```
@implementation UIColor (EPPZRepresenter)


NSString *NSStringFromUIColor(UIColor *color)
{
    const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%f, %f, %f, %f]",
            components[0],
            components[1],
            components[2],
            components[3]];
}

UIColor *UIColorFromNSString(NSString *string)
{
    NSString *componentsString = [[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"]" withString:@""];
    NSArray *components = [componentsString componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:[(NSString*)components[0] floatValue]
                           green:[(NSString*)components[1] floatValue]
                            blue:[(NSString*)components[2] floatValue]
                           alpha:[(NSString*)components[3] floatValue]];
}


@end
```

The same formatting that is used by NSStringFromCGAffineTransform. This is actually a part of a bigger scale plist object representer in [eppz!kit at GitHub][1].