# storing uicolor in plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist

I am trying to store UIColor in plist.I seen many links but none of those not given accurate answer.some of my sample code is below

```
CGColorRef color=[MyColor CGColor];
NSUInteger numComponents = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(color);
const CGFloat *components=CGColorGetComponents(color);

NSArray *colorArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(float)components[0],(float)components[1],nil];
```

it is giving Not working for me can any one tell me the exact answer to store uicolor into plist.Thanks in advance.Your suggestion is important for me.Please provide sample snippet rather than posting links.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone UIColor in Plist file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911998/iphone-uicolor-in-plist-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to store the individual colors separately (RGBA, if that is the color space you are using) in an array of `NSNumber`s.

```
NSNumber *red = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:components[0]];
NSNumber *green = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:components[1]];
NSNumber *blue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:components[2]];
NSNumber *alpha = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:components[3]];

NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:red, green, blue, alpha, nil];
```

The reason for this is that you can only add *objects* to a `NSArray`. A `float` or `CGFloat` is not an object.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion i ll go with this.can i store nsnumber directly into the plist.

Comment: You can, but I recommend using an array.